# First solidity DApp, Unhandled Runtime Error

Tags: typescript, next.js, blockchain, solidity, hardhat

I am writing my first Solidity DApp with Next.js and Hardhat and I am running into an error.  I have successfully deployed my contract on a local blockchain via `npx hardhat node`.  The trouble I am running into pertains to the `getProposalCount()` function and I am having difficulty figuring out how to fix it.

Here is the link to my GitHub repository for this specific project if anyone would like to try to reproduce the error: https://github.com/blakelucey/voting-dapp-project

Here is the error in question:

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: call revert exception [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-CALL_EXCEPTION ] (method="getProposalCount()", data="0x", errorArgs=null, errorName=null, errorSignature=null, reason=null, code=CALL_EXCEPTION, version=abi/5.7.0)
```

Be aware that when deploying my VotingContract.sol I was only able to deploy it with this input to `proposalNames` `"1"`.  I am not sure why this is, I attempted inputting an array of strings, and an array of strings formatted as BigNumbers.  Unfortunately, `"1"` is the only input that worked.

This is my smart contract:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.18;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

contract VotingContract is Ownable {
    struct Proposal {
        string name;
        uint256 voteCount;
    }

    Proposal[] public proposals;
    uint256 public proposalCount;

    constructor(string[] memory proposalNames) {
        proposalCount = proposalNames.length;
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < proposalNames.length; i++) {
            proposals.push(Proposal({name: proposalNames[i], voteCount: 0}));
        }
    }

    function getProposalCount() public view returns (uint256) {
        return proposalCount;
    }

    function getProposal(
        uint256 proposalId
    ) public view returns (string memory, uint256) {
        require(proposalId < proposals.length, "Invalid proposal ID");
        Proposal storage proposal = proposals[proposalId];
        return (proposal.name, proposal.voteCount);
    }

    function vote(uint256 proposalId) public {
        require(proposalId < proposals.length, "Invalid proposal ID");
        Proposal storage proposal = proposals[proposalId];
        proposal.voteCount++;
    }
}
```

Be aware that within my index.tsx nothing that I have attempted to `console.log` within my `useEffect` has appeared in the console.

This is my index.tsx:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { ethers } from "ethers";
import {
  Typography,
  Button,
  Container,
  ThemeProvider,
  createTheme,
  Stack,
} from "@mui/material";
import VotingContract from "../../bin/src/contracts/VotingContract.json";

const contractAddress = "0xDc64a140Aa3E981100a9becA4E685f962f0cF6C9"; // Replace with your contract address
const contractAbi = VotingContract.abi;

interface Proposal {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  description: string;
}

const theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    mode: "dark",
    primary: {
      main: "#0f0",
    },
    background: {
      default: "#111111",
      paper: "#212121",
    },
  },
  typography: {
    fontFamily: "Open Sans",
    h1: {
      fontFamily: "Ubuntu Mono",
    },
    h2: {
      fontFamily: "Ubuntu Mono",
    },
    h3: {
      fontFamily: "Ubuntu Mono",
    },
    h4: {
      fontFamily: "Ubuntu Mono",
    },
    h6: {
      fontFamily: "Ubuntu Mono",
    },
    h5: {
      fontFamily: "Ubuntu Mono",
    },
    subtitle1: {
      fontFamily: "Ubuntu Mono",
    },
    subtitle2: {
      fontFamily: "Ubuntu Mono",
    },
    button: {
      fontFamily: "Ubuntu Mono",
      fontWeight: 900,
    },
    overline: {
      fontFamily: "Ubuntu Mono",
    },
  },
});

function VotingApp() {
  const [proposals, setProposals] = useState<Proposal[]>([]);
  const [selectedProposal, setSelectedProposal] = useState<number>(0);
  const [voted, setVoted] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [provider, setProvider] =
    useState<ethers.providers.Web3Provider | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchProviderAndData() {
      if (
        typeof window !== "undefined" &&
        typeof window.ethereum !== "undefined"
      ) {
        const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
        console.log("provider: ", provider);
        setProvider(provider);
        const contract = new ethers.Contract(
          contractAddress,
          contractAbi,
          provider
        );
        const proposalCount = await contract.getProposalCount();
        console.log("proposalCount: ", proposalCount.toString());
        const proposals = [];
        for (let i = 1; i <= proposalCount; i++) {
          const proposal = await contract.functions.proposals(i);
          console.log("proposal: ", proposal);
          proposals.push({
            id: i,
            title: proposal.title,
            description: proposal.description,
          });
        }
        console.log("proposals: ", proposals);
        setProposals(proposals);
      }
    }

    fetchProviderAndData();
  }, []);

  console.log("This has been read!");

  async function handleVote() {
    if (provider) {
      const signer = provider.getSigner();
      const contract = new ethers.Contract(
        contractAddress,
        contractAbi,
        signer
      );
      const transaction = await contract.functions.vote(selectedProposal);
      await transaction.wait();
      console.log("voted: ", voted);
      setVoted(true);
    }
  }

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Container>
        <Stack spacing={2}>
          <Typography variant="h1" align="center">
            Voting App
          </Typography>
          {proposals.map((proposal) => (
            <div key={proposal.id}>
              <Typography variant="h3">{proposal.title}</Typography>
              <Typography variant="body1">{proposal.description}</Typography>
              <Button
                variant="contained"
                color="primary"
                onClick={() => setSelectedProposal(proposal.id)}
              >
                {selectedProposal === proposal.id ? "Selected" : "Select"}
              </Button>
            </div>
          ))}
          <Button
            variant="contained"
            color="primary"
            onClick={handleVote}
            disabled={!selectedProposal || voted}
          >
            Vote
          </Button>
          {voted && (
            <Typography variant="h5" align="center">
              Thank you for voting!
            </Typography>
          )}
        </Stack>
      </Container>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}

export default VotingApp;
```

And here is my terminal output after deploying my contract:

```
scripts % npx hardhat run deploy.js --network localhost

VotingContract deployed to: 0xDc64a140Aa3E981100a9becA4E685f962f0cF6C9
```

```
 Contract deployment: Lock
  Contract address:    0xdc64a140aa3e981100a9beca4e685f962f0cf6c9
  Transaction:         0x30ea6a068de0112a4d504fcc9dc4b918b437a0c89251ab070971f9b4e502768a
  From:                0xf39fd6e51aad88f6f4ce6ab8827279cfffb92266
  Value:               0 ETH
  Gas used:            426897 of 2000000
  Block #5:            0x58979de60048e74231335845ec625bd0d9925c5b67dd72bdcfd36166e4a4eb55
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

After take a look a your repo, I believe the problem lies in the deploy script

`const VotingContract = await ethers.getContractFactory("Lock", provider);`

You used the `Lock` contract from hardhat example, instead of your contract.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  However, I had to use that name to deploy my contract because the compiled version of my smart contract is called "Lock.sol".  I'm not sure why the name was changed when "VotingContract.sol" was compiled, but that seems to be the case.  Also, when I attempted to deploy using "VotingContract" instead of "Lock" in the line of code you mentioned I was unable to deploy.

Comment: please check the arguments, you need to pass an array. In your repo at the time I check, you just use a string (uint256 in solidity, fit the arg type for the Lock contract)

Comment: I had tried passing in an array of strings like `["1", "2", "3"]` and it would throw an invalid BigNumber error.  This was the error:  `Error: invalid BigNumber value (argument="value", value=["1","2","3"], code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=bignumber/5.7.0)`.  Do you have any suggestions as to why this might be?